# MongoDB: Search for a string in a collection and return only matched collection items

Tags: json, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have the following json saved in the mongoDB:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "1753242",
        "TYPE": "8003"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "ID": "4823034",
        "TYPE": "7005"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

When i want to search for a specific TYPE, I can do it like this:

```
db.geo.find({"features.properties.TYPE":"8003"})
```

My problem is, that this query returns the whole json and not just elements with the TYPE "8003".
Does anybody know, how to retrieve just elements with the TYPE "8003" by query?

Comment: You can try something like this `db.geo.find({},{"features":{$elemMatch:{"properties":{"TYPE":"8003"}}}})` or alternatively `db.geo.find( { "features.properties.TYPE":"8003"},
                    { "features.$": 1 } )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the Mongo db 3.2 release, you can use the new [$filter](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) aggregation operator to filter an array during projection, which includes all the matches in the array

```
db.test.aggregate([
{$match: {'features': {$elemMatch : {"properties.TYPE": '8003' }}},
{$project: {
    features: {$filter: {
        input: '$features',
        as: 'feature',
        cond: {$eq: ['$$feature.properties.TYPE', '8003']}
    }}
}}
]);
```

If you just want the `first` element of the results, you can use the positional [$](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/) operator like below :

```
db.geo.find( { "features.properties.TYPE":"8003"}, { "features.$": 1 } )
```

Comment: @PhilippHellmayr: May be the issue is with the match query, I've updated my answer above, Please check and let me know if it's working.

Answer (score 1):

**$elemMatch** operator returns only first element matching the **$elemMatch** condition in query result.

Please try executing following query

```
db.geo.find({
    features: {
        $elemMatch: {
            "properties.TYPE": "8003"
        }
    }
  }, {
    features: {
        $elemMatch: {
            "properties.TYPE": "8003"
        }
    }
  })
```

Please refer the documentation of **$elemMatch** operator as described in below mentioned URL

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/elemMatch/